# App Review - Do they allow app names with question marks in?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, xcode, app-store-connect

I have submitted my app to the app store 6 times and always been rejected because apparently the `UIRequiredCapabilities` key is not set correctly.

Well, I've tried many different combinations of things and cannot seem to figure it out and they are not helpful at all.

Doing more research today, I found this https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/apple-store-rejection-uirequireddevicecapabilities/57029/5

The chosen answer says that his issue was because his app name had a question mark in. Is this true, do Apple not allow question marks in the app's title?

My app has a question mark do obviously I would try that (even though it does ruin my app name), but I am a bit fed up of submitting and waiting so I figured it would be good for me and other people in the same situation to have a definitive answer.

EDITED with full rejection message:

```
Guideline 2.3 - Performance - Accurate Metadata


We were still unable to install the app on iPad and iPhone . The
UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key in the Info.plist is set in such a way that
the app will not install on an iPad and iPhone.

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please check the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key to
verify that it contains only the attributes required for your app features or
the attributes that must not be present on the device. Attributes specified by
a dictionary should be set to true if they are required and false if they must
not be present on the device.
```

Comment: What is the full reason that Apple gives for the rejection?  Usually the full message says what part of the key wasn't set correctly.

Comment: I've edited with the full message

Comment: I've added an answer to your specific question about *question marks* in the title. However, any further question about the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key in the `Info.plist` would be off-topic here as you're then venturing into a software development question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### **IT IS A BUG**

I opened up a Technical Support Incident with Apple, and they told me it could very well be a bug and that I should raise a bug report.

They also told me to use TestFlight so I can test the app in the same way the Review team would:

> 1. I tested it and was unable to install, it just came up with an error
> 2. I then changed all mentions of my app name, and removed the offending question mark
> 3. I tested it again and it installed just fine

**If you have this same issue:**

> - Change all occurrences of your app name ( I did this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370175/how-do-i-completely-rename-an-xcode-project-i-e-inclusive-of-folders
>     )
> - Change the Bundle Display Name is info.plist to contain your original name (with the question mark)

**That's it!**

Your app will look and work exactly the same, it will just be different in Xcode. This is just a workaround until they actually fix the bug, which according to the link in my question, has been around since 2016...

Comment: Righto, so Monomeeth's answer was correct then? You can use a question mark in the name and the problem was something else? So you spoke to Apple and then found out what the other problem was, some sort of bug, right? And it's a temporary bug?

Comment: Well not really, he said "the issue you're having had nothing to do with the name of your app". As I've discovered, it actually is a problem with having a question mark in your app name in Xcode and this answer could help people in the same situation. And it should be temporary, but it's clearly existed for two years.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with @user2397282 it was being rejected because my xcode project has question mark on my project. Had to remove all question marks for it to be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes, the use of a question mark (?) is perfectly acceptable in the name of an iOS app, so the issue you're having has nothing to do with the name of your app.

By way of evidence, below are three examples of apps that have question marks in their name:

- [Where's that Wally?](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wheres-that-wally-needle-hay-stack-seek-er-look-for/id900878408?mt=8)
- [What's the difference? Spot it](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/whats-the-difference-spot-it/id820452091?mt=8)
- [What does my name mean??](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/what-does-my-name-mean/id492296532?mt=8)

As you can see, question marks are fine. The third one even has two question marks.